# change the tab order of components in Net Beans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created, in NetBeans, four JTextField like this:

```
TextField1             TextField3
TextField2             TextField4
```

when I start the program the first TextField selected is number 1, after pressing Tab I want that the TextField2 get selected, but instead it goes to the TextField3. I would like to know if there is any property in which I can put the order in which to traverse this objects in Java.

I remember that other languages, like .Net, have that property in the properties toolbox, but I cannot found it in the NetBeans GUI.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a NetBeans bug. I use simply Notepad++, jGRASP, and exe4j. If you would reply with some suspicious code snippets or simply the whole Java file.

Answer (score 0):

Put the 2field infront of 1field it may be possible that control always go to corresponding component and in many apps it is and is recommended too for a good user friendly GUI

Comment: I dont want to reorder all the components that I have, better is to have the tab property

Comment: Then you may use action listener for this say if you put a check that if 1field has \t then set a string "" in 2field which will allow you having your control in 2field try it i am giving you hints

Comment: But it is recommend for a user friendly GUI that the control will go to corresponding field because your user is expecting the caret to placed in correspong field and yes it is you may try it using any form based java app

Comment: Read the above post get some ideas

Comment: you are not suppose to get the fixes at all so you have to get the ideas and transform them as you want Thanks